# How can I average numbers using Soulver?

Tags: macos

I have a license for the excellent app, [Soulver](http://www.acqualia.com/soulver/). I'd like to use it to find the average of some integers. I'd like to do something like:

```
avg(199, 262, 219, 268, 285, 293)
```

However, that doesn't work:

[image]

Any suggestions on how to do this with Soulver?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Soulver doesn't let you do this with an operation, but there are a few ways to do it. First of all, there's the old fashioned way:

[image]

Add your numbers up (in parentheses) and then divide by the number of numbers.

There's also a more automated but less convenient way. Soulver can calculate the average of the results (blue column) that are currently in your document:

[image]

But, if you want to use that average later, you'll have to do a bit more.

Select Average, then click on `Copy Selected Statistic`.

Add a new line to your Soulver document: `avg =` and then paste in the average. You now have an average that you can rever to via `avg`:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Soulver can only calculate the average of the results in the right column. To display you have to click on the "Total:" in the bottom line of the window:

[image]